# SQL Error returned in Union query

Tags: sql

receiving the error "expected something between the word 'gcv' and the 'AND' keyword. Now i've tried placing a "WHERE" between the two and i get "Something expected between the 'WHERE' keyword and the "AND" keyword. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
                            `SELECT  gcv.i_pln,
             gcv.c_typ_cov,
             gcv.d_eff,
             gcv.d_eff_pln,
             gcv.c_sta,
            gcv.d_sta,
            gcv.c_mde_bft_fst,
            gcv.a_bft_fst,
            gcv.c_mde_bft_sec,
             gcv.a_bft_sec,
            gcv.c_mde_bft_trd,
             gcv.a_bft_trd,
             gcv.p_cre_hom,
             gcv.c_cl_rsk,
             gpv.c_val

            FROM Pearl_P.tltc906_gcv gcv,

            pearl_p.tltc912_gpv gpv




           WHERE  gcv.i_pln > 0
            AND gcv.i_pln = gpv.i_pln
            AND gpv.i_prv = 36

         UNION

             SELECT
             gcv.i_pln,
             gcv.c_typ_cov,
             gcv.d_eff,
             gcv.d_eff_pln,
             gcv.c_sta,
             gcv.d_sta,
             gcv.c_mde_bft_fst,
             gcv.a_bft_fst,
             gcv.c_mde_bft_sec,
             gcv.a_bft_sec,
             gcv.c_mde_bft_trd,
             gcv.a_bft_trd,
             gcv.p_cre_hom,
             gcv.c_cl_rsk,
             ''


            FROM Pearl_P.tltc906_gcv gcv



            AND NOT EXISTS(
            SELECT 1
            FROM pearl_p.tltc906_gcv gcv,
             pearl_p.tltc912_gpv gpv

            WHERE  gcv.i_pln > 0
            AND gcv.i_pln = gpv.i_pln
            AND gpv.i_prv = 36)
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS
```

instead of

```
AND NOT EXISTS
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix this area:

```
FROM Pearl_P.tltc906_gcv gcv
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM pearl_p.tltc906_gcv,
         pearl_p.tltc912_gpv
) AND gcv.i_pln > 0
  AND gcv.i_pln = gpv.i_pln
  AND gpv.i_prv = 36)
```

The logic may still be wrong - it looks suspect. But this should at least run.

Answer (score 0):

It is the second part of your query:

```
FROM Pearl_P.tltc906_gcv gcv
```

--Something needed here before the AND

```
        AND NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM pearl_p.tltc906_gcv gcv,
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this...

```
        FROM Pearl_P.tltc906_gcv gcv



        AND NOT EXISTS(
```

Either you want to apply that to the WHOLE unioned result...

```
SELECT * FROM (
  <query 1>
UNION ALL
  <query 2>
)
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (...)
```

Or you're just missing the `WHERE` statement where you have the `AND`